# Webpack builds on production environment

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, npm, webpack

In React JS starter kits like the one at https://github.com/wallacyyy/reactly-starter-kit, I see package.json files that have content like this:

```
"scripts": {
   "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config ./webpack.prod.config.js --progress --colors",
...
},
"dependencies": {
  "express": "^4.15.2",
  "react": "^15.5.4",
  "react-dom": "^15.5.4"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "webpack": "^2.2.1",
  "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.2"
}
```

The build script uses webpack to process the production build.  How is it able to run on production when webpack is only a devDependency?

Comment: It doesn't run on production, it just passes a variable `NODE_ENV` with value `production` which is required to set some config to production mode like minification.

Answer (score 2):

Webpack doesn't run on your production environment. Your `build` script just sets the `NODE_ENV` variable to equals `production` and thus letting Webpack and his plugins know they should prepare the bundle for production use. What exactly happens when you run this command depends on your webpack configuration, but among most common things would be code minification. You can also specify different kind of source maps and many other things. See https://webpack.js.org/guides/production/ for more information.

Comment: Thanks! How does the bundle get transferred to the production environment? If you were deploying to heroku, the source gets pushed, but AFAIK the bundle does not get checked in to the repo.

Answer (score 0):

You keep both prod and dev webpack config. And in prod webpack config use definePlugin to set process.env.NODE_ENV as production ( you can also use other env variables ).

Now during transpiling and minification, NODE_ENV will be used in your vendor lib or in you app js.

```
'use strict';

 var webpack = require('webpack');
 var uglifyPlugin = new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
  minimize: true,
  comments: false
 });

 var definePlugin = new webpack.DefinePlugin({
   'process.env': {
    'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
  }
 });

 var commonChunkPlugin = new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
  name: 'vendor',
  chunks: ['vendor', 'source'],
  filename: 'vendor.bundle.js'
 });

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname + '/jsFolder',
  entry: {
    source: ['./app.jsx'],
    vendor: [
        'react',
        'react-dom',
        'redux',
        'axios'
    ]
},

output: {
    filename: "[name].bundle.js"
},

resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
},

module: {
    loaders: [
        { test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader' },
        {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            query: {
                presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0']
            }
        },
        { test: /\.css$/, loader: "css-loader" },
    ]
},

plugins: [commonChunkPlugin, definePlugin, uglifyPlugin],

node: {
    console: true,
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty'
},

 target: 'web'

};
```